# After upgrade to 23.04, virtual consoles are missing

Tags: upgrade, kubuntu, virtual-console, 23.04

I have just upgraded my Kubuntu installation from 22.10 to 23.04. AFAICT, everything went smoothly. But after the upgrade, the virtual consoles at Ctrl+Alt+F# are missing: if I press e.g. Ctrl+Alt+F2, the screen is switched to a text-mode screen showing the kernel error messages (just like during the boot time), without a login prompt; no keys seem to work there. Ctrl+Alt+F1 switches back to the GUI.

I looked into `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` and everything is commented there, including a `#NAutoVTs=6` line. Should I uncomment that line? (Why? Was this an expected change?) Or is the problem somewhere else? Where?

Comment: I am using normal Ubuntu 23.04 (upgraded from 22.10) and I _do_ have Ctrl+Alt+F3 .. F6 virtual consoles. All lines in `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` are commented too.

Comment: This is a video card driver problem more speficially with the framebuffer. Pick another video card driver. There is an issue with at the least the 390 nvidia driver.

Comment: According to Driver Manager, I’m now using “NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-525“. Are you saying I should switch to nouveau for the consoles to work? Is this a known bug, tracked somewhere?

Comment: I am using exactly the same driver too (nvidia-driver-525), but I have no such problem. (Hardware product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Mobile])

Comment: Same problem with 23.04. Nvidia driver 535. I do not know if it worked with 22.10, because I never tried it. I do not think it's a driver problem, because switching to text mode obviously works.